# Python Descriptor's - Documentation unclear

Tags: python, namespaces, descriptor

I was looking at python's descriptor's documentation [here](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html), and the statement which got me thinking is:

---

For objects, the machinery is in `object.__getattribute__()` which transforms `b.x` into `type(b).__dict__['x'].__get__(b, type(b))`

---

under a section named [Invoking Descriptors](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html#invoking-descriptors).

Last part of the statement `b.x into type(b).__dict__['x'].__get__(b, type(b))` is causing the conflict here. As per my understanding, if we lookup for attribute on an instance, then `instance.__dict__`is being looked up, and if we didn't find anything `type(instance).__dict__` is referred.

In our example, `b.x` should then be evaluated as:

`b.__dict__["x"].__get__(b, type(b))`     **instead of**

`type(b).__dict__['x'].__get__(b, type(b))`

Is this understanding correct? Or am I going wrong somewhere in interpretation?
Any explanation would be helpful.

Thanks.

I am adding the second part as well:

Why instance attributes does not respect the descriptor protocol? For ex: referring to code below:

```
>>> class Desc(object):
...     def __get__(self, obj, type):
...         return 1000
...     def __set__(self, obj, value):
...         raise AttributeError
... 
>>> 
>>> class Test(object):
...     def __init__(self,num):
...         self.num = num
...         self.desc = Desc()
... 
>>> 
>>> t = Test(10)
>>> print "Desc details are ", t.desc
Desc details are  <__main__.Desc object at 0x7f746d647890>
```

Thanks for helping me out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your understanding is incorrect. `x` most likely does not appear in the instance's dict at all; the descriptor object appears in the class's dict or the dict of one of the superclasses.

Let's use an example:

```
class Foo(object):
    @property
    def x(self):
        return 0

    def y(self):
        return 1

 x = Foo()
 x.__dict__['x'] = 2
 x.__dict__['y'] = 3
```

`Foo.x` and `Foo.y` are both descriptors. (Properties and functions both implement the descriptor protocol.)

When we access `x.x`:

```
>>> x.x
0
```

We do not get the value from `x`'s dict. Instead, since Python finds a data descriptor by the name of `x` in `Foo.__dict__`, it calls

```
Foo.__dict__['x'].__get__(x, Foo)
```

and returns the result. The data descriptor wins over the instance dict.

On the other hand, if we try `x.y`:

```
>>> x.y
3
```

we get 3, rather than a bound method object. Functions don't have `__set__` or `__delete__`, so the instance dict overrides them.

---

As for the new Part 2 to your question, descriptors don't function in the instance dict. Consider what would happen if they did:

```
class Foo(object):
    @property
    def bar(self):
        return 4

Foo.bar = 3
```

If descriptors functioned in the instance dict, then the assignment to `Foo.bar` would find a descriptor in `Foo`'s dict and call `Foo.__dict__['bar'].__set__`. The `__set__` method of the descriptor would have to handle setting the attribute on both the class and the instance, and it would have to tell the difference somehow, even in the face of metaclasses. There just isn't a compelling reason to complicate the protocol this way.

Comment: What if we have something like:

>>> class Desc(object):
...     def __get__(self, obj, type):
...         return 1000
...     def __set__(self, obj, value):
...         raise AttributeError
... 
>>> 
>>> class Test(object):
...     def __init__(self,num):
...         self.num = num
...         self.desc = Desc()
... 
>>> 
>>> t = Test(10)
>>> print "Desc details are ", t.desc
Desc details are  <__main__.Desc object at 0x7f746d647890>

Why instance attributes does not respect descriptor protocol?

Comment: I have added the second part as well, please update the answer and provide the explanation.

Comment: @RahulTanwani: Answer expanded.

Comment: The second part is still unclear. If we have a non-data descriptor without __set__ (like a property itself), doesn't it makes sense to respect the descriptor protocol? Referring to the example in question, t.desc should return 1000 instead of returning a desc object.

Comment: @RahulTanwani: Properties all have `__set__`; they just raise an `AttributeError` if you don't give them a setter. As for properties that don't have `__set__`, the same issues crop up with `__get__` and `__delete__`. It's just not worth complicating the descriptor protocol to include instance descriptors.